# Automapper with EnumMapping throws on nullable Enums with unknown value

Tags: .net, enums, automapper

I have a nullable enum property on the source side and get this property with value 0 instead of NULL.
But 0 is not a represented value in the enum so AutoMapper with `ConvertUsingEnumMapping` throws an exception that the enum can not be mapped. Is there a way to map it to `NULL` whenever the value is not represented in the source enum? Some way to prevent this runtime error?

```cs
public class SomeSourceDto
{
    public SomeSourceEnum? SomeEnum { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDestinationDto
{
    public SomeDestinationEnum? SomeEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum SomeSourceEnum
{
    First = 1
}

public enum SomeDestinationEnum
{
    First = 1
}
```

Mapping configuration:

```cs
CreateMap<SomeSourceDto, SomeDestinationDto>();
CreateMap<SomeSourceEnum, SomeDestinationEnum>().ConvertUsingEnumMapping(opt => opt.MapByName());
```

Mapping:

```cs
var someSourceDto = new SomeSourceDto { SomeEnum = 0 };
Mapper.Map<SomeDestinationDto>(someSourceDto);
```

Exception:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
>
> Error mapping types.
>
> ...
>
> Destination Member:
>
> SomeEnum

My current workaround is to apply this before the map:

```cs
someSourceDto.SomeEnum = someSourceDto.SomeEnum == 0 ? null : someSourceDto.SomeEnum;
```

Is there a better way? I can't use `ConvertUsingEnumMapping` when I make the enum types in the map nullable.

The problem is that this can happen for every enum property so I'm at big risk of runtime errors atm because I have no control over the source side of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can work it around like this:

```
CreateMap<SomeSourceDto, SomeDestinationDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dst => dst.SomeEnum,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            src => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SomeDestinationEnum), src.SomeEnum) 
            ? src.SomeEnum 
            : null));
```

You can rewrite this to an extension method so you can use it more easily for other DTO's

Comment: Does not work for me. https://github.com/matthiaslischka/AutoMapperNullEnumIssue/blob/MapProperty/AutoMapperNullEnumIssue/UnitTest1.cs